# javascript getElementsByTagName exclude certain tags

Tags: javascript, parsing, xml-parsing, rss, atom-feed

In my project I'm trying to parse rss & atom feeds. I target each feed's link with this:

```
var feedLink = source.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
```

Some feeds start directly with

```
<link>http://www.url.com</link>
```

but some start like this:

```
<atom:link href="http://www.url.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link>http://www.url.com</link>
```

and the selector I'm using targets also the link tags that starts with atom:
Is there a way to avoid them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try poping out the link from the end of **NodeList**, in this case, it will work for both cases.

```
var x = source.getElementsByTagName('link');
var feedLink = x[(x.length - 1)]
```

Isn't the best solution, but is the more fastly in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `getElementsByTagNameNS` instead, but i'm not sure how well it is supported across browsers. Works in latest Chrome.

```js
var xmlString = [
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>',
  '<feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">',
  '<atom:link href="http://www.example.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />',
  '<link>http://www.example.com</link>',
  '</feed>'
].join('\n');
var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

// Try regular search
var found = xml.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
  console.log('regular', i, found[i].nodeName);
}

// Try namespaced search
var foundNS = xml.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'link');
for (var i = 0; i < foundNS.length; i++) {
  console.log('namespaced', i, foundNS[i].nodeName);
}
```